# Sed number flag over multiple lines

Tags: macos, unix, sed

This is a very basic command that is baffling me. On my mac terminal, I can't seem to do a sed nth replacement over multiple lines in a file. Am I missing a tag or a setting or something?

On one line, this works:

```
>echo "hi hi hi" > atest.txt
>sed s/hi/hello/2 atest.txt

output: 
hi hello hi
```

On multiple lines, it doesn't

```
>echo "hi
hi
hi" > btest.txt
sed s/hi/hello/2 btest.txt

output: 
hi
hi
hi
```

Given every basic manual says this should work, I'm not feeling so smart right now.

Comment: The second of these previous posts seems to do the trick: $ tr '\n' '^' < btest.txt | sed 's/hi/hello/2' | tr '^' '\n'. But only that part - the other tricks with sed only don't. One point being that many of the sed tutorials out there are absolutely wrong. It works with a single line string, not over multiple lines, unless you do something else or use awk.